# Mobile Version Discrepancy

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, web-frontend

I'm trying to make my first personal portfolio website. Everything looks like it should through the browser and through multiple mobile emulators. However, on my actual iPhone 5 (and checked on others as well), I see the desktop (and not the mobile) version.

I'll link to two images below that will hopefully help show my problem.

I'm not sure what actual code to post. My style file includes an `@media screen and (min-width:768px)` for things like hiding the navbar header on desktop screens, and my html includes bootstrap classes that should be responsive.

If you need any specific code snippets, let me know. In the meantime, I have it all hosted on github: (github.com/julianstanley/julianstanley.github.io)

[| Desktop View Alongside Mobile Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL6Uh.png) 
[| Actual Mobile View |](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll1Rz.jpg)

Comment: try adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to your HTML

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I already have that metadata in the header (https://github.com/julianstanley/julianstanley.github.io/blob/master/index.html)

Edit: I just noticed that I put `width=divice-width` there. That may fix it: I'll update this if it works.

Comment: Checked your website & there are multiple typos in it. `content="width=divice-width, inital-scale=1.0"`. It says "divice-width" not "device-width". Also it says "inital-scale=1.0" not "initial-scale=1.0"

Comment: There we go, that fixed it! Thanks for catching that (& I'll try to be more careful to check for typos before I post on here again!)

Comment: Sure. Happy coding. Just in case, always have the habit of checking your developer "Console" tab. These typos were highlighted there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nikhil Nanjappa answered this question in the comments above. The `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` is important for viewpoint and, while I had remembered to put that line in, I made a typo.